# Capture group in substitute function

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, substitute

I try to do a substitution from a vim script and to operate over a captured group like so:

```
let string = "{b1} {b2} ({b3})"
echo substitute(string, "{\([^}]*\)}", "a", "g")
```

It doesn't match anything and the result doesn't change.

If I remove the `\( \)`:

```
echo substitute(string, "{[^}]*}", "a", "g")
```

Then the whole `{b1}` is replaced with `a`, when I only want to replace the content of it: `{a}`.

I have read that the pattern in the substitute command always work in `magic` mode. And that in the magic mode, the capture group is: `\( \)`.

Do you know the trick to make this work?

**Edit:**
Thanks to Christian Brabandt I was able to make it work (see his answer below). I had to change the `\( \)` to `\zs \ze` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In double-quote strings, the backslash has a special meaning. And will probably be skipped when parsing the quoted string. The details can be seen at `:h expr-quote`. You would have to double the slashes to make that work.

Therefore, it is usually easier to read and maintain using single quoted strings. See `:h literal-string` as there the backslash won't be skipped.

Comment: Do you know a usecase where the `expr-quote` is a better use than a `literal-string` ?

Comment: When you need keys like in `:exe ":norm! afoobar\<esc>"` or when you need special chars e.g. \xe4

Comment: I see, meanwhile I found http://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml where this is explained also :)